# Is database recovery from EF model possible?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I had a web service project, with a database integration of course :) I use Entity Framework, so I generated my EF model from my db (sql server express). Everything was okay till my computer got broke. I had my project files backed up so I recovered them. But I didn't have the db backup(shame).

As far as I know there is this concept `Code First`, and what I am wondering is can I use it to regenerate my db? Otherwise I'll have to try getting the db from the old disk, or rewriting the whole db.

Before going into those struggles I wanted ask and get a proper answer to this since I thought it could help others too.

Comment: Does [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456815(v=vs.100).aspx) applies to your case ?

Comment: I guess so, I will look into that ;)

Comment: I just got the chance to look at it, and it was really easy. I right clicked the model, then said Generate Db from model, POOF! sql script was there. Then running it on sql server finished the job :) btw I was actually a little surprised since the old db was mysql and new is sql server and it still worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can.

Specify a connection string in your DbContext constructor, which points to a non-existent database, and the database will be created from scratch.

The EF workflows are "reversible" in the sense that you can go from DB to model or from model to DB, no matter if the model is a graphic EDM or a DbContext.

Comment: Thank you sir I will certainly try it.