# Entity Framework Code First Database Recovery Model

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Is is possible to set the Recovery Model mode of an SQL database created using Entity Framework 6? I know it's possible to set it through the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER DATABASE [Database_Name] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
```

It seems odd that this can't be set as a part of the configuration of the `DbContext` - the object which creates the database can't seem to control *how* it's created. I was expecting to find something like the following:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        // This is where I would have expected to be able to set the recovery model type
        Database.RecoveryModel = RecoveryModelType.Simple;
    }
}
```

My suspicion is that this isn't possible due to EF being (largely) DB provider agnostic and recovery model being MSSQL specific, but I'm hoping that I'm wrong.

Comment: Of course, you can

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594365/is-database-recovery-from-ef-model-possible

Comment: @Coding4Fun just because that question has 'recovery' in the title, doesn't mean it's talking about the same thing - it isn't.

Comment: @Coding4Fun The linked question doesn't address the question I asked, which is specifically about setting the recovery model type through EF. The database is being created absolutely fine, but the recovery model is always the default; that is, full.

Comment: The fact that this https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlDdlBuilder.cs (which is where `CREATE DATABASE` is to be found in the EF6 source) doesn't include any mention of "recovery" suggests that the answer is no.

Comment: That said, [`IDatabaseInitializer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998931/what-is-the-correct-use-of-idatabaseinitializer-in-ef) looks relevant

Answer (score 1):

Not in a way you want it to.

EF works with different SQL providers and what is relevant for MS SQL, might be inappropriate for MySQL.

However you can always run raw TSQL and do whatever you want.